# How can I perform operations on a group of arrays in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, transpose

Having a group of arrays, e.g.

```
C3_mu, Cp3_mu, C4_mu, Cp4_mu, Cz_mu,
C3_beta, Cp3_beta, C4_beta, Cp4_beta, Cz_beta
```

I want to perform operations on them in a for loop.

I've tried the following:

```
channels = [C3_mu, Cp3_mu, C4_mu, Cp4_mu, Cz_mu,
            C3_beta, Cp3_beta, C4_beta, Cp4_beta, Cz_beta]

for chan in channels:
    chan = np.transpose(chan)
```

but soon realized that, in this way, "chan" would be replaced by the array itself, and I can't see the right way of doing this.

Comment: Add the transposed channels to a new list.

Comment: Or, use enumerate and replace the elements at their indices.

Comment: Are these already `numpy.array`s or can they be of different type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate)

```
for i, chan in enumerate(channels):
    channels[i] = np.transpose(chan)
```

Comment: @VictorO.Costa Awesome! If so, you could accept my answer (or the other answer: it's a good solution as well).

Answer (score 3):

You can use a list comprehension:

`channels = [np.transpose(chan) for chan in channels]`